# How to suspend video when video is in opening and preparing state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tizen, tizen-web-app

How to suspend video when video is in opening and preparing state?

I mean to say that if I open video and press smart hub and launch other application video that time how to suspend video when video in open or prepare state.

I am using this code for multitasking.

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
 if(document.hidden){
      webapis.avplay.suspend(); //Mandatory. If you use avplay, you should call this method.
 } else {
       webapis.avplay.restore();
 }});
```

When video is in open or prepare state then video is going to play instead of suspend.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if the 'visibilitychange' function is triggering as your plan.

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
 if(document.hidden){
     alert("To Suspend Video now");
 } else {
      alert("To Restore Video now");
 }});
```

If thats okay then go throught the documentation for [AVPlay API](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/api-references/samsung-product-api-references/avplay-api)

Documentation of suspend() states the Constraint:

To be called in these states - "PAUSED", "PLAYING"

Use getState() function to ensure the state.

Exceptions are mentioned also. Catch the Exception that is thrown to debug.

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {

    console.log("Player state: " + webapis.avplay.getState());
    if(webapis.avplay.getState() === "PLAYING")||(webapis.avplay.getState() === "PAUSED"){

        if(document.hidden){
            try {
                console.log("In Suspend block");
                webapis.avplay.suspend();
            } catch (e) {
                console.error("Error in Suspend:"+e);
            }
        }   
        else {
            try {
                console.log("In Restore block");
                webapis.avplay.restore();
            } catch (e) {
                console.error("Error in Restore:"+e);
            }

        }
    }
    else
        console.log("Constraint not met");
});
```